# I applied two validation on same field in spring boot application but when both the validation failed the sequence of message always chaange

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, annotations

In my spring boot project I applied validation on same field name merchantReferenceID one is `c@NotBlank` and another is pattern please find below code for your reference when both the validation failed then the message is not consistent sometimes it shows "Merchant Reference Id cannot be blank or null, Invalid Merchant Reference Id", and sometime "Invalid Merchant Reference Id, Merchant Reference Id cannot be blank or null",

My requirement is the message should be consistent it should show same message sequence in each request without any custom validation please find below request class.

```
@ApiModel
public class SanctionCheckStatus {
    @Schema(required = true, description = "Merchant Reference Id", example = "343403938493", minLength = 1, maxLength = 100)
    @NotBlank(message = "Merchant Reference Id cannot be blank or null")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9-]{32,36}$", message = "Invalid Merchant Reference Id")
    private String merchantReferenceID;

//getter and setter
}
```

I tried change the sequence and not blank to not empty but still same issue.